# Chrome data compression proxy error

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, youtube-api, mobile-chrome

When I use youtube video upload API on mobile phone it uploads the video but before redirect to the redirect_url, most of the times it throws this error:

url with error: http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/action/FormDataUpload/FSVfvf45g45g4FFDSGSdfgr24g3t34t3EFVFFDSFGgg3435?nexturl=http://my-redirect-url.com:80/uploaded

> This page cannot be loaded via the chrome data compression proxy. Try reloading this page.

when I just reload the page it redirects to the right redirect_url and the video is uploaded appropriately.

What might be a solution to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I am the tech lead for the Chrome data compression proxy. We happen to have some special case logic to deal with YouTube URLs in the proxy which would cause this, but this seems not to be working as expected. Can you give me an example of your use of the API? Is this a POST request? Seems like something we should be able to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube or Google updated something in apps/youtube_api (unclear what) but when I accesses the app console it was different, then I created a new app and it worked.