# Chrome data compression proxy error with jquery ajax form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, mobile-chrome

I have a simple web page with a form that gets submitted via ajax using jquery. The form works fine when submitting it on a desktop browser, but the form gets an error when submitted using Chrome on a mobile device that has the "chrome data compression proxy" feature enabled.

I get the following error message:

> This page cannot be loaded via the "chrome data compression proxy. Try reloading this page.

After doing a bit of searching around, there are a few "similar" questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830384/chrome-data-compression-proxy-error) and more notably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088658/chrome-data-compression-proxy-and-dwr), but neither quite help me.

The seconds question is supposedly answered by the lead of the "Chrome data compression proxy" I've tried the suggestion in the second questions answer which is to set the Cache-Control header to no-transform. But that made no difference.

Has anyone had similar issues and have a work around for this?

This is the code I'm using to submit the form:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "services/users/changePasswordUsingToken",
    data : {
        'token' : token,
        'md5pwd' : md5pwd
    },
    headers : {
        'Cache-Control': 'no-transform'
    },
    success : function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
        ...
    },
    error : function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText); //This page cannot be loaded via the "chrome data compression proxy. Try reloading this page.
    ...
});
```

Comment: I have the same problem, hope for an answer!

Comment: I think the "Cache-Control" header needs to be set on the server, rather than in the JavaScript.

Comment: @EddieSullivan, `Cache-Control` is available on both sides. It allows the client to request that none of the proxies/intermediate caches transform the data before it reaches the server. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the tech lead for the Chrome compression proxy.

This error message is sent when the proxy can't access the site for some reason - e.g., a DNS resolution error, or if the site is not on the public Internet (e.g., an intranet). Normally, for GET requests the browser would be able to reload the URL automatically without using the proxy, but this is not possible with POST.

Can you provide some more details on where this site is hosted and whether it's behind a private network? I've seen a couple of reports of this and I'd like to come up with a general solution. Thanks.

Comment: I've got this with an intranet IP on POST as well.

Comment: Then why don't you give a more descriptive error message? Tell that you cannot find/reach the page. Because now we ask ourselves why a page could not be loaded. And what did you have in mind adding `Try to reload the page`? What should be done there?

Comment: @mdwelsh what you say would explain why I was getting that problem. I was developing locally, connecting my Android device to my server running on my laptop via my home wifi network. The proxy would never have gotten to that. I am however still getting problems with that ajax request, this time the response is totally empty and has no reason for failure but I'm not convinced it's related to this same issue. I will have access to that project in the next week or two and will update here. That said, it would have saved massive amounts of time if the error message was more meaningful for devs.

Comment: @mdwelsh It seems this was the problem. I've managed to get it working in my prod environment with the data compression feature enabled.

Comment: Could you please explain how you fixed it? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: The fix is one of two things: 1) Turn of the Chrome data compression feature while in dev. 2) Make sure the URL/service being called is accessible to Google. I.e. public. It won't work if you're testing on an internal network. Or as mdwelsh mentioned, could also be DNS resolution issues. Just make sure the proxy can hit your url, or turn off the compression feature.

Comment: For local dev purposes, it would be nice if by default it would ignore all top-level *.local domain requests.

Comment: Is there anything server can do to prevent CCP breaking requests like this?

Comment: Not sure how this is the accepted answer, even if @mdwelsh has replied since the "answer" is only a request for more info (which would have been better as a comment on the question) and doesn't contain any fix at all.

Comment: It very much answered the question, explaining how the google compression proxy will attempt to reach the host, but being internal (locahost), it can't reach it, resulting in the error.

Comment: Hi Julz - I'm glad you managed to work around it, but I don't think you ever provided the details I requested in my original reply. 

Ideally, Chrome should know not to send a request to the Data Saver proxy when Google can't access the site. We already avoid doing this for URLs based off of 'localhost', 127.0.0.1, etc. but of course for other DNS names there's no way for Chrome to know a priori that this is not going to be accessible. Can you provide a little more detail? It may be possible for us to find a general fix.

Comment: Hi mdwelsh I did detail in a previous comment but here's some more. My setup was all running on my internal LAN with the server application(the one hosting the web page) running on my laptop, which would have had an IP of say 196.168.1.3. Then on my mobile connected to my LAN with IP say 196.168.1.5 accessing the web page hosted on my laptop from chrome. So 127.0.0.1 or localhost exclusion would't have applied here. Unless the compression proxy knows it's running on an internal LAN the only way I can see to get around this is to disabling the compression setting in this type of scenario.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317109/js-form-submit-this-page-cannot-be-loaded-using-chrome-data-saver-try-reloadin

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem by accessing local server from mobile by machine name, like:
http://scabbiaza.local:3000

Started using access by IP and got rid off this issue.